# Disable p:datatable with javascript

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2.2

I want to disable a primefaces `dataTable` to avoid that a new row can be selected (but a prior selected row shall be displayed). Is this possible? The `dataTable` is inside a modal `p:dialog`. I tried it with `p:spotlight` but it seems like that `p:spotlight` is not working inside a modal `p:dialog`.
Is there another possibilty? With or without javascript?

Comment: how is this jsf related? javascript is client-side, jsf does not run client-side. So these three tags are superfluous

Comment: It is a primefaces JSF dataTable and my question was if there is a possiblity...should I tag all my questions with HTML because all is HTML at the end?

Comment: No, but since you explicity mention javascript, and PrimeFaces it is about client-side manipulating the datatable. So there no jsf aspect in this.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
  <p:dataTable disabledSelection=#{bean.isLocked} ...
```

Now all you have to do is to set the boolean `isLocked` parameter in the backing bean and update the datatable.

Comment: Sorry my question was not unclear. I have a selection in the table and prevent to change that selection. I update my question. If I set this attribute the table does not show a selection.